# Seeing Lock on SQL Database - Azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm connecting SQL Database to a **PHP** website (Both are on Azure),

Everything in PHP seems to be fine, and Connection String is also Perfect.
When I try to connect to a database it connects and does all the operations, but when I try to connect to another database it show the following error.

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => 08001
    [SQLSTATE] => 08001
    [1] => 5
    [code] => 5
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => HYT00
    [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
    [1] => 0
    [code] => 0
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => 08001
    [SQLSTATE] => 08001
    [1] => 5
    [code] => 5
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or
          instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a
          connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible.
          Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured
          to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server
          Books Online.
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related
        or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a
        connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible.
        Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to
        allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books
        Online.
    )
  )
```

And also,
I'm seeing this **Lock** sign on the database which is not getting connected.

[image: lock image]

This Lock doesn't appear on the database, which connects successfully.
And also All three (Two Databases and a Web App) are on **Same Resource Group**.

I'm connecting both database using **Connection String** stored on website's **Application Settings**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is **TDE** (Transparent Data Encryption) icon rather than a **Lock** sign. See [Transparent Data Encryption with Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-with-azure-sql-database).

And according to the error message above, the most likely cause of this issue is that the **Server name** you are using is incorrect. Here are some proposals for you to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Make sure the hostname from **Connection String** exactly equals to the Server name in the Azure portal.

[image]

2. Use the sample code for PHP to test whether the connection could be established or not. Do not forget to replace with your own password.

[image]